# Can't check if user input is smaller than some number

Tags: java

There is no problem when I input a number smaller than 12 but when I input something bigger I get the "Enter a number smaller than 13" and always get that in subsequent inputs. How can I make it so that the program checks both for int and a number smaller than 13?

```
package com.company;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner z = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean cont;
        boolean isNumber;

        do {
            System.out.println("Enter the number you want to see the factorial of (0-12)");
            do{
                if(s.hasNextInt()){
                    isNumber = true;
                }else{
                    isNumber=false;
                    System.out.println("Enter a number");
                    s.next();
                }
            }while(!isNumber);
            int input = s.nextInt();

            boolean isSmall;
            do{
                if(input < 13){
                    isSmall= true;

                }else{
                    isSmall=false;
                    System.out.println("Enter a number less than 13");
                    s.next();
                }
            }while(!isSmall);

            int factorial = 1;
            System.out.print(input + "!" + " = ");
            for ( int i =1 ; i<=input ;  i++) {
                factorial *= i;
                System.out.print(i);
                if (input == i) {
                    break;
                }

                System.out.print(" * ");
            }
            System.out.println(" = " + factorial);

            System.out.println("Do you want to continue?");
            String line = z.nextLine();
            if(line.matches("y|YES|Y|yes|Yes")){
                cont=true;
            }else{
                cont= false;
                System.out.println("Thanks for using the program!");
            }
        }while(cont);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not reading the next int before doing your next comparison. I'd recommend creating a getNumberMethod that could have all logic necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not reading the next int in your second do-while loop before comparing again. I'd recommend creating a separate method to retrieve a valid number.

```
private static int getValidInt(Scanner s) {
    System.out.println("Enter the number you want to see the factorial of (0-12)");

    int input = getInt(s);
    while (input < 0 || input > 12) {
        System.out.println("Enter an integer between 0 and 12.");
        s.next();
        input = getInt(s);
    }
    return input;
}

private static int getInt(Scanner s) {
    while (!s.hasNextInt()) {
        System.out.println("Enter a number");
        s.next();
    }

    return s.nextInt();
}
```

Then you can remove your 2 inner do-while loops and replace it with `int input = getValidInt(s);`

This also will ensure that the input is always an int greater than 0 which your code was missing though the message stated it as a requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to put new value into input, so you always compared value bigger 13

```
do{
    if(input < 13){
         isSmall= true;
     }else{
           isSmall=false;
           System.out.println("Enter a number less than 13");
           input =  s.nextInt();
      }
  }while(!isSmall);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually set input to the number they enter after you give them a warning. Right now, you're just constantly looping because input remains the same no matter what they enter.

```
        boolean isSmall;
        do {
            if (input < 13) {
                isSmall = true;

            } else {
                isSmall = false;
                System.out.println("Enter a number less than 13");
                input = s.nextInt();

            }
        } while (!isSmall);
```